# Inserted formula with cell reference does not recognize new input

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I swear this just worked yesterday...

I have a program that creates formulas within certain cells that depend on subsequent data entries into other cells:

```
Cells(i, 40).Formula = "= (N" & i & ")/AP" & i
```

So, AP*i* can be input and/or changed after the fact, and the formula should give you the result for whatever value is there.  However, I get a #Div/0! error no matter what value is in that cell.  When I evaluate the formula (within Excel) and step through the calculations, it shows this (for one particular cell):

= (N64)/AP64  = (47.35)/AP64  = 47.35/AP64  = **47.35/9**  = #DIV/0!

So, the formula recognizes that there is a value in the cell AP64, but then does not use it to properly calculate the result.

As I said at the top, this worked as I expected yesterday afternoon when I was testing it.  Now that I need other people to start using it, of course, it doesn't.  I changed nothing within the program relative to these lines of code.

I apologize if this is answered elsewhere - I really have no idea how to create a search for this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

1) Value of the cells used is formatted to a number (i've had #Value based on that a couple times) and

2) verify that modifying the code using fixed references provides the appropriate output ("A16" for some reason wasn't recognized as a cell reference in one I had show up).  E.g., "$N" & i & "/$AP" & i

---

If those both look alright, you might try something like:

```
.Range(.Cells(3,40),.Cells(lr,40)).Formula = "=$N3/$AP3" 'ensure no random spaces
```

This should act like a fill-down in which the # 3 is iterated with the same row as the formula.

Comment: It is recognized as a number (I can write other formulas within the sheet and it will read the values in those cells and calculate correctly).        The original formula reads the correct cell references, as shown by the Excel formula evaluation - it *sees* the "9" written in the cell; it just doesn't *use* it properly.   I think it has something to do with formulas calculating "automatically"(?), but I can't figure out how my program might have changed that setting.