# Formulas become unresponsive to changed value inputs to referenced cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013

The question closest to mine did not return a satisfactory answer.

[Inserted formula with cell reference does not recognize new input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51636878/inserted-formula-with-cell-reference-does-not-recognize-new-input)

In a particular macro-enabled workbook, macro-generated formulas do not change output values when data in referenced cells is changed. For instance, I can enter some numbers in referenced cells and the formula-containing cell will show the calculated number, but those numbers will not change when changing the data in the references. Manually typed formulas in the same workbook show the same behavior regardless of being in or outside range objects or in non-macro generated worksheets within this workbook. It doesn't seem to be specific to any particular formula.

I checked that the cells are formatted as numbers and that the formulas are valid. Formulas still appear in the cells after computing values.

Reloading the same workbook without macro-enabling shows the formulas working correctly.

In another macro-enabled workbook no problem is observed.

I checked property settings in the VBA editor and found no differences between them.

It seems like something is going on related to macro-enabling and not any particular code that is causing formulas to become unresponsive, but I am stumped as to what that could be.

Here is the formula in which I noticed the problem:

in "=d4:d21" the array formula "{=IF(ISNUMBER(C4:C21), C4:C21/C3, "0")}"

Even with a simple formula placed anywhere on the sheet like "=average(f4:f6)", this problem occurs.

I think creating the macro containing these lines of code is when the issue started, but they are not specific to it:

```
Sub CreateDataSheet()

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Range("d4:d21").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
"=IF(ISNUMBER(RC[-1]:R[17]C[-1], RC[-1]:R[17]C[-1]/R[-1]C[-1], ""0"")"

End Sub
```

How can I get these formulas to work again?

Comment: Calculation is definitely set to Automatic?

Answer (score 0):

The calculations in the workbook were set to 'manual' and I changed it to 'automatic'. The formulas work now.